# how ecommerce sites save images in mysql database and retrieve it?

Tags: mysql, database

I am curious about how the images are stored in database for ecommerce website.

If I have to store an image in database I would use clob. But using clod where I retrieve the image back from db to show on website it will take time. How can I reduce this time?

Answer (score 0):

Generally images are saved on file system and image url saved on db. There are background job for adding advertisement to images and creating thumbnails. If you use thousand of image you must save images on file system for performance.
Also you can use online storage services like as Amazon S3. These services are cheaper than hosting disk price and not use your hosting bandwidth.